# Jenkins post-build action trigger boolean parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have build-pipeline job i Jenkins  which goes like this

Job-1 --triggers -> Job-2 and Job-3. sometimes I want to trigger only Job-2 but not Job 3. I setup  Boolean parameter ( from Parameterized Trigger Plugin) which has check boxes  for "True" or "false".  I have set up the boolean parameter in post-build action of Job-1 and  regardless of the check box value, all of my downstream Jobs ( Job-2 and Job-3)always get triggered.

Is there a way to trigger  skip some of downstream jobs using a parameter.

Above is an example, My actual pipeline has lot of jobs with using Java( maven), Powershell, Shell scripts, batch etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your job3, you can use the Conditional Step plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

In the build section, add a Conditional Step (single) using on the boolean parameter set by the job1:

- Run: Boolean condition
- Token: ${JOB1_BOOLEAN}

Cheers,
Bruno